# How to copy just the files in a folder in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, backup

```
        source = ('C:\\Qualys Report\\Qualys Data\\')
        dest1 = ('C:\\Qualys Report\\Backup\\')           
        for filename in os.listdir(source):
            if filename.endswith('.csv'):
                shutil.move(source+filename, dest1)
```

For some reason its moving the folder and csv file i have into the backup folder

Anyway i can just move the file itself?

Comment: Which folder was moved? _source_ or the _folder inside_ the source? Please specify it.

Answer (score 1):

From the question it seems you are simply trying to copy the csv files from a single source dir (not recursively), you should use copy not move/rename if you wish to keep the original copy in place, with a copy in dest1.

```
    import os
    source = ('C:\\Qualys Report\\Qualys Data\\')
    dest1 = ('C:\\Qualys Report\\Backup\\')

    for filename in os.listdir(source):
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            shutil.copy(source+filename, dest1)
```